# Docker - spring boot application connectivity with mysql

Tags: windows, spring-boot, docker, java-8

I am new to docker and trying something. Created a spring boot rest api with name employee services. It actually takes data from a mysql database emp_db. Which is working perfectly. Now I am trying to dockerize the same stuff.

**application properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I am running below command to pull and configure mysql

```
docker run  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd -e MYSQL_DATABASE=emp_db --name mysql_name mysql
```

It starts perfectly as I get below message

```
2021-02-08T09:08:46.018218Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-02-08T09:08:46.051985Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

but when I start service I am getting below error.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-08 09:11:38.235 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the port to be able to access MySQL from outside the container:

```
docker run  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd -e MYSQL_DATABASE=emp_db -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_name mysql
```

Comment: I tried this but getting same error when I start service.

Comment: You are setting the root password when running the container but trying to use another user to connect to it?

Comment: I am using same password for starting container and to connect to the service.

Comment: 2021-02-08T10:17:20.085726Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-02-08T10:17:21.433250Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-02-08T10:17:24.392032Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-02-08 10:17:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized

Comment: root@localhost is created with an empty password !!   is this is this problem ? How this is possible ?